# Reactjs custom element rendering by string

Tags: reactjs, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I have a question while using React.js

I got some strings from backend
And I need to input them in my react jsx DOM

Backend gives me these string

```
from Backend => 
let testString = '<TestTag />'
```

I just want to execute DangerouslyInnerHTML

```
from Frontend =>

const TestTag = styled.div`
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: yellow;
`

function Example() {

  const html = `
    testString
  `
  return (
    <InnerHTML html={html} />
  )
}
```

Displaying yellow box is expected,
But empty element is printed

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you saying you want the string literal to render, i.e. you don't want "TestTag" to be interpreted as a custom html tag?

Comment: @DrewReese No, exactly opposite, sorry for my bad English. I want to render custom tag  (the yellow box!) by recived string

Comment: You can't, via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, which is for HTML text. In your example `TestTag ` is a react component. Sounds like you want to [Choose the Type at Runtime](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime). Or maybe you just need some CSS in scope that targets that tag and applies the style.

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for replying me. 
you mean, [ displaying react component by string ] is impossible in anyway?

Comment: React components are functions, not strings, so a string literal of the JSX isn't the same as JSX that the React framework is maintaining and processing. React components aren't rendered in the DOM as elements, only what they return from their render function is rendered into the DOM.

Comment: @DrewReese I should consider using html inline style. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing out the syntax. Also it does not work within React element. Render it inside

Correct syntax to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML is

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
```

Comment: Oh, I used npm library, <InnerHTML> tag means dangerousltySetInnerHTML